# Hg / Mercurial forbid commits in specific branches

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisesvn

As a small team we are using Hg to track our work, but we have to interface with another program which is bigger and shitty. That being said, it is very important for us to make sure that the code we check - in into this cm is never compromised by other branches code that were not checked-in.

What we decided is to have a branch that will be synced with this CM tool, and we will merge nothing into it. However, we need to make sure that no one is ever going to merge something into that branch.

So this is my question: if we are 3 users A, B and C, and we have branched default, Ab, Bb, and Cb how can we:

Authorize A to commit into default, but not B and C
Authorize A, B and C, to commit into all the others branches
Forbit all other merges than default into Ab, Bb, Cb (so, merging Ab with Bb should be forbidden).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage precisely the access rights on each repo/branch, you could install *mercurial-server*. See its documentation at http://dev.lshift.net/paul/mercurial-server/docbook.html

You can then specify the acess control you want in an ASCII access.conf file, e.g.,

```
write user=group/A_dsa.pub repo=name branch=default
read  user=group/** repo=name branch=default
etc...
```

You will not be able to differentiate on the types of commits though (merge or not, merge from where..).